# Connectivity Issue in Talend Studio

Tags: java, talend

I am new to Talend Studio. I designed a job to transform data from phpmysql to phpMysql itself. The following error occurs:

```
java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
......
Exception in component tMysqlOutput_1
java.lang.NullPointerException
at routines.system.RunStat.sendMessages(RunStat.java:286)
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 4041
```

However the port 4041 in the console error is shown differently at different turns of run. The actual port is 3306. What could be the reason for this connectivity problem?Is this because of installation error?Please help.Thanks.

Comment: In tMysqlOutput_1 component what have you given for host and port?? and tell me what have you given for tMysqlInput_1 also..

Comment: Please tell us your DataBase Connection Metadata.

Answer (score 0):

The statistics port has nothing to do to your data. This socket is used by Talend itself to send, as the name states, statistics to Talend Enterprise Engine execution engine (basically, the premium version)